# Excel vba Make a text appear temporarily

Tags: vba, excel

So I've been searching everywhere for a way to temporarily show a text box in excel. Basically, what I'm trying to show a text for 5 seconds after the user clicks the button. I don't want anyone to "do the code for me" but instead give me pointers. The user clicks a button to switch language. When that button is pressed, I want a message to appear saying: "All values have been reset". My question is the following: Is there a function in excel-vba that show a textbox for a certain amount of time before disappearing or turning his visibility value to false?

All the rest of the code to switch the language has already been done I'm really only looking to find the function that turns off the visibility after time. (a timer or i don't know)

I doubt showing the code I have so far would help but if you wish to see it, indicate it in the comments.

Thank you SO

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Ok_Click()

startTimer
Unload Me

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub startTimer()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "NextTime"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub NextTime()

If Sheet3.Range("B5") = 0 Then reset
If Sheet3.Range("B5") = 0 Then Exit Sub
Sheet3.Range("B5").Value = Sheet3.Range("B5").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
startTimer

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub reset()

Sheet3.Range("B5") = ("00:00:05")

End Sub
```

Comment: `been searching everywhere` but didn't find `application.wait`???

Comment: Just setup a form, show the form modeless and setup a timer for 5 seconds with `OnTime` to hide the form again.

Comment: I'll try both these functions and comment what worked better for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Here is my code so far:

    Private Sub Ok_Click()
        startTimer
        Unload Me
    End Sub

    Sub startTimer()
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "NextTime"
    End Sub

    Sub NextTime()
        If Sheet3.Range("B5") = 0 Then reset
        If Sheet3.Range("B5") = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Sheet3.Range("B5").Value = Sheet3.Range("B5").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
        startTimer
    End Sub

    Sub reset()
        Sheet3.Range("B5") = ("00:00:05")
    End Sub

Comment: How do I write this in code?  I've tried adding 4 spaces in front but it doesn't seem to work @Ralph

Comment: Oh thx!
Now when I debug it skips the NextTime part I don't know why and then at the end a message appears saying: "Impossible to use the macro NextTime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Call BoxMaker

    DoEvents
    DoEvents

    newHour = Hour(Now())
    newMinute = Minute(Now())
    newSecond = Second(Now()) + 5
    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
    Application.Wait waitTime

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SPLASH").Delete
End Sub


Sub BoxMaker()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 217.5, 51#, _
        482.25, 278.25).Select
    Selection.Name = "SPLASH"
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Please Wait for Macro"
    With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=21).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 36
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer. *(+1)* from my side. Still, I am wondering if this could be improved by using [Application.Ontime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx). Then the user could still continue to work during these 5 seconds. Of course, the user could delete the shape during that time an therefore you'd have to check first the collection of `Shapes` on the sheet if the shape `SPLASH` still exists. What do you think?